# Is there a way to effectively change the year dash(ex. 1976-1977) to a processable one?

Tags: python, pandas

I was just practicing and got stuck here.
I was trying to convert my Date(dtype was object) to int data. But when I typed in

```
pd.to_numeric(df.date)
```

it gave me

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "1976-77" at position 5
```

and it seems that although the df I have mostly is written in int format(ex. 1977) it does have quite a lot that is written like the above(1976-77)

I do understand that I can just ignore those and type in

```
pd.to_numeric(df.date, errors='coerce')
```

But, I was wondering if there is a way to handle those data with dashes too? Maybe by modifying all the data containing "-", leaving them with only the year in front of them? e.g. convert "1967-1968" to "1967"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 'Dates' is your column then following might help:

```
df['NewDates']=df['Dates'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split("-")[0])
```

Just splitting on dash and retaining first element

Comment: You framed your question pretty well despite being new to SO. Kudos and welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `apply` you can perform `str` operations directly on Dataframe column using the `str` function

```
In [36]: df = pd.DataFrame({"date":["2020-2021","1964-1965","1999-2000"]})

In [37]: df
Out[37]:
        date
0  2020-2021
1  1964-1965
2  1999-2000

In [38]: df["NewDates"] = df.date.str.split("-",expand=True)[0]
Out[38]:
0    2020
1    1964
2    1999
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Won't work for OP's case as there is a mix of formats. When using in build str operation of pandas, the elements not having the delimiter pattern will return NAN.

Comment: No, it won't @JALO-JusAnotherLivngOrganism

Comment: Will work only when entire column has string format. Try on df['Dates']=[1977,'1977-1988',1988]